# React router installation issue

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-audit

....whenever I'm trying to download the react router then it is showing 6 vulnerability.
There's written, to fix run the command "npm audit fix" and "npm audit fix --force" but still that problem is bothering.
Visuals in ss.[image]

I've tried commands suggested to solve this problem.

Comment: Simply ignore it. You will have to wait for the package you depend on (react-scripts) to update their dependencies. `npm audit` is an absolute dumpster fire.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)